# Jscript - getting before and after value on a numbers only textbox

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have this function that validates if a number is typed onto my textbox:

```
function mudavalor(sender, event) {
    var stringAntesDepois = sender.value;
    if (event.keyCode > 47 && event.keyCode < 58) {
        stringAntesDepois += String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    }

    sender.value = "";
    sender.value = stringAntesDepois;
}
```

Calling by:

```
<input class="texto" runat="server" onkeydown="mudavalor(this,event)" id="Text1" type="text" />
```

The problem is that, oddly enough, if I don't put an `alert(event.keyCode)` before the IF line, it doesn't work. If I do it like this:

```
function mudavalor(sender, event) {
    var stringAntesDepois = sender.value;
    alert(event.keyCode);
    if (event.keyCode > 47 && event.keyCode < 58) {
```

Then it works just fine.

I need to do:

1 - Check if the key typed is a number between 0-9

2 - Update the "Text1" field if it's a number

3 - After ANY changes on the "Text1" field, I need to assign his value onto a label

PS: I can't use the "number" type for HTML5

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/snr00qng/

You should use `event.preventDefault()` for ignoring keys, or to say, ignore default behavior.

this is you should probably want to do:

```
function mudavalor(){
   if(event.keyCode>=48 && event.keyCode<=57){
      document.getElementById('txt').textContent+= String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
   }
   else
     event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. I made it work through a different way:

var x = parseInt(sender.value);     
        if ( x < 0 || isNaN(x) ) {
            alert("Only numbers above 0!");
            sender.value = "";
            sender.style.border = "3px solid red";
        }

That way I can show the user where he typed wrong

Comment: isNaN works when the user types a letter or number+letter combination, whereas x<0 works if the user types an illegal number